# Struts application - unable to download file through https on IE

Tags: internet-explorer-8, https, download, struts

I have a Struts application that at some point offers the possibility to download some files.
I recently found out that download fails through https on IE 8. With Firefox 4 is working fine.

The error I get in IE is:

> Internet Explorer cannot download
>   someAction.do from localhost.
>
> Internet Explorer was not able to open
>   this Internet site.  The requested
>   site is either unavailable or cannot
>   be found.  Please try again later.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everyone who used file downloads on HTTPS is likely to have hit this problem with Internet explorer.

[If a user tries to download a file over a HTTPS connection, any response headers that prevent caching will cause the file download process to fail in Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/02/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https-when-no-cache.aspx).

There are lots of references to this kind of issue on the Microsoft Support site also (e.g. [Internet Explorer file downloads over SSL do not work with the cache control headers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308))

Comment: Thanks. I managed to unset all cache related header properties in the response and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found that we need to add headers

```
Cache-control: "no-cache"
```

and
`Pragma: "no-cache"`.

to make ur app compatible with IE8.
Unfortunately this is not working for me.

Comment: Here's what worked for me; set the cache-control to private for IE and no-cache for non IE browsers