# ASP.NET MVC 3 File download: Not Working in IE8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8, download, fileresult

I have the Download that simply serves a static zip file from the local file system that works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE8.

The website is running on localhost with SSL, but I am getting the following error message in IE.

> Unable to download Download/ from localhost.
>
> Unable to open this Internet site. The requested site is either
>   unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later.

```
public ActionResult Download(long batchID)
{
    var batchFilePath = string.Format(BatchOrderReportsFolder + "\\Batch-{0}\\Batch-{0}.zip", batchID);
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(batchFilePath)) {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
    }

    return File(batchFilePath, "application/zip", Path.GetFileName(batchFilePath));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried  `FileResult` instead of `ActionResult` (not sure if that's MVC4 only)?

Comment: I removed the if block and set the return type to FileResult, but I got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what ultimately worked for me. In my case, there was a global ActionFilter on OnActionExecuted that was setting cache-control to "no-cache".

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
     var browserInfo = Request.Browser.Browser;
    if (filterContext.Result is FileResult) {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.CacheControl = browserInfo == "IE" ? "private" : "no-cache";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The information in the following question should help you...

[Struts application - unable to download file through https on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544804/struts-application-unable-to-download-file-through-https-on-ie)