# Download File from FileResult without saving to disk

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, download

I am using MVC 4.

I have a method in my controller which generates a CSV file on demand and I want this file to be then downloaded by the user without the need of saving it to the disk at the server side. So I am passing a MemoryStream on the File() object to avoid having to firstly save file to disk and later give him the path for download.

Controller Method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GenerateCsv(string data)


    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb = GetCsvReportToString(data);

    var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString()));

    return this.File(stream, "text/csv", "ReportCsv.csv");
}
```

sb (StringBuilder) has the correct data, as I have debugged it and confirmed it.

my javascript code:

```
window.open(generateFileLink + '?data=' + dataToSend, '_blank');
```

The window gets in fact opened, the download dialog appears but with an error, saying that it cannot be downloaded from localhost:

[image]

The name is different in the download "ReportToCsv" because I didn't use real names for methods in my question, but doesn't matter.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: If you want to black out the "ServerFilesCompare" part of the file name you'll need to do it on the dialog in the background as well.

Comment: You don't need to put the Bytes[] into a MemoryStream. The File Object can Take the Byte Array as it is. And shouldn't it be HttpPost instead of HttpGet?

Comment: @DaveParsons that in fact really helped me solving my problem :)

Comment: errrr..... glad I could help?!

Comment: @Ralf it should be a Get, because i am passing the parameter through the URL. So it's a GET. Well I don't NEED to, but that doesn't really make a difference here :(

Comment: Have you tried this suggestion by adding Cache-Control header - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846054/asp-net-mvc-3-file-download-not-working-in-ie8

Comment: @filipehd: if you have solved the problem it would be good if you could share the answer with us all - if you feel it's too trivial etc then you can always delete the question.

Comment: @DaveParsons I was being ironic... I was just commenting that your comment was just useless and didn't help in anything. I asked the community for help and you answered me that I forgot to black out the ServerFilesCompare...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11267754/1417487

It's a regarding the headers of cache, for IE versions 6-8.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb=GetCsvReportToString(data);
            return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString()), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "ReportCsv.csv");
```

Comment: Didn't make any difference. Still getting the same error. I will try @ramiramilu solution. It may be in fact a problem with the Headers because my solution works on Chrome

Comment: @filipehd:Actually above code worked fine with IE 10 in my system. Not sure why you are getting error.

Comment: the error only occurs in IE versions 6-8. So it both my code and yours work on IE10 :)