# Sending model to controller action to export as csv

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a large set of data that my users can filter by various options.  I'd like to export this set of data as a CSV, but not sure how to send the item to my controller action.

The following code in my index.cshtml file:

```
@model Project.ViewModels.PeopleIndexViewModel
<a href="@Url.Action("Export", "Person", new { List = Model.People.ToList()})" title="Export to CSV">
    <img src="/content/images/excel.gif" />
</a>
```

Turns out to be empty when I hit the controller:

```
public ActionResult Export(List<Person> List)
{
    // List is empty here...
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you've defined valid route in RouteConfig.cs file. To return csv file controller see below post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566595/download-file-from-fileresult-without-saving-to-disk/23570561#23570561

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion it won't work that way. I would suggest keeping the List in Session or TempData like that:

```
Session["PeopleList"] = list;
```

or

```
TempData["PeopleList"] = list;
```

This way you might access it between requests. Remember - storage in Session is for Session duration. Storage in TempData is only till the next request unless you use Keep method.