# Saving an XML file in a different directory from a custom action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I update the following code to save in a directory of my choice on IIS. Currently it will only save in my downloads directory with the file name of the path.

E.g.. the following example saves in my downloads directory as

**C--inetpub-wwwroot-sitename-Feeds-reports.xml**

```
[HttpGet]
public XmlActionResult GetXmlData()
{
    System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("~/reports.xml"));
    var xml = XElement.Load(reader);

    //I want to save the file to the following destination but this saves it with the file name of the destination in my downloads directory

    return new XmlActionResult(xml.ToString(), Server.MapPath("~/Feeds/reports.xml"));
}
```

**EDIT**

I want to move the reports.xml file from the current directory to the Feeds directory.

Comment: Is XmlActionResult is your custom ActionResult? If you want to save file why are you returning ActionResult?

Comment: XmlActionResult is a custom action

Comment: so you want to move reports.xml file from current directory to Feeds directory. I'm not getting what you are trying to achieve using above code?

Comment: You don't show anywhere how you are trying to save a file. Can you show us what you are trying to do?

Comment: If you want to save file,see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566595/download-file-from-fileresult-without-saving-to-disk/23570561#23570561

Comment: @malkam, Yes that's what I want to do.

Comment: Then simply use File.Move(src,dst) method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx